# Incremental CDC from Postgresql for a subset of rows

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant, debezium, cdc, aws-dms

I have a postgresql DB which has tables containing multi-tenant data. Example:

**Table Customer**

| CustId | Cust Name |
| --- | --- |
| First | CustA |
| Second | CustB |

**Table CustomerShoppingDet**

| Item Name | CustId. | Buying Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | CustA | 02-13-2023 |
| Second | CustA | 03-14-2023 |
| First. | CustB | 04-14-2023 |

These are all on AWS RDS scattered across regions. Lets assume, `CustA` probably exists only in us-east region. Now I have a use case wherein I need to move `CustA` from us-east (say - source) to eu-central region RDS (say - destination). So, I need to migrate all `CustA` related data.

The data per customer is quite large and spans across multiple tables (~18GB per customer). We are thinking of replicating a snapshot as Phase I and using CDC I will sync all delta updates from source to destination until the D-Day when the switch happens from source to destination. We will disable CustA on source for a brief time before enabling it at the destination.

This is primarily for 2 reasons:

- Minimise the overhead of exporting the data for CustA in multiple chunks and phases. Not all tables have a `modified_date` column
- Minimise the overall `switch` time from source to destination

Any suggestion on a suitable CDC replication mechanism that I can use here. I have gone through Debezium and AWS DMS offering but I am not completely sure if they will allow filtering on only `CustA` records.

I can even build my own export, transform and load pipeline if that can offer me greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical decoding in PostgreSQL v15 or better, where `CREATE PUBLICATION` supports a `WHERE` condition. You need to define a publication for each tenant. Then the subscriber will only receive changes for that tenant.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz . All our current postgresql instances are at version 14.7 and to move them to 15 involving downtime would be an uphill ask. Anything that can be done with older Postgres versions?

Comment: No. But `pg_upgrade` can be fast, no matter how big the database is.

Comment: As I mentioned in another thread - we don’t want to go via this route since creating and monitoring publication for thousands of tenants is problematic and we need to do it on demand whenever the export is triggered.

Comment: You can create publications when you need them. You don't have to move all tenants at once, right?